# Angular 4, Conditional display with ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

help to fix condition to display data.
I get model of M through async service, so i use >model?.something< notation to avoid errors when model is still undefined. title is null or 'somestring'.
Something wrong with expression. Whatever form i choose it always display one of cases.
I have avoided this type expression early and can not translate correctly to typescript.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { M } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
<p *ngIf="model1?.title !== null">
  Display text if title exist('common string')
</p>
<p *ngIf="model2?.title === null">
  Display text if title equal to null
</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent {
  model1: M;
  model2: M;
  constructor() {
    this.model1 = {
      title: 'username'
    };
    this.model2 = {
      title: null
    };
  }
}

export class M {
    public title: string;

    public constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: there's nothing happening async here.

Comment: idk whats your problem here, can you explain more?

Comment: instantiate model class,  model1: M = new M();

Comment: @PrithiviRaj Why would this make a difference here? You don't even know if his model actually has a constructor.

Comment: @lexith You are right error should not come with the given sample but error will occur if he tries to give title like this.model1.title='username' so only he's getting error like model is undefined. May be the real code is missing here

Comment: Now i see conditions were right, I have writen a plunker to reproduce an error, and it worked correctly. The error was at backend: at the begging username is null, but after clearing it become equal to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try:

```
<h1 *ngIf="model1.title!==null">
    OK
  </h1>

   <h1 *ngIf="model2.title!==null">
    OK
  </h1>
```